# SQL запрос нужна помощь

Tags: sql

Всем привет,есть такая бд некой тур фирмы

```
CREATE TABLE Country_destination( 
id int NOT NULL, 
Name varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT Country_destinationPK 
PRIMARY KEY (id)); 

CREATE TABLE City( 
id int NOT NULL, 
Name varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT CityPK 
PRIMARY KEY(id)); 

CREATE TABLE Tour( 
id int NOT NULL, 
Price int NOT NULL, 
Date date NOT NULL, 
Time_Tour timestamp NOT NULL, 
Cityid int NULL, 
CONSTRAINT TourPK 
PRIMARY KEY(id), 
CONSTRAINT Tour_CityidFK 
FOREIGN KEY (Cityid) 
REFERENCES City (id));

CREATE TABLE Client( 
id int NOT NULL, 
Firstname varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
Secondname varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
Number int NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT ClientPK 
PRIMARY KEY(id)); 

CREATE TABLE Type_Transport( 
id int NOT NULL, 
Name varchar(255) NULL, 
CONSTRAINT Type_TransportPK 
PRIMARY KEY (id)); 

CREATE TABLE Treaty( 
id int NOT NULL, 
Number int NULL, 
Tourid int NULL, 
Clientid int NULL, 
Type_Transportid int NULL, 
CONSTRAINT TreatyPK 
PRIMARY KEY(id), 
CONSTRAINT Treaty_TouridFK 
FOREIGN KEY (Tourid) 
REFERENCES Tour (id), 
CONSTRAINT Treaty_ClientidFK 
FOREIGN KEY (Clientid) 
REFERENCES Client (id), 
CONSTRAINT Treaty_Type_TransportidFK 
FOREIGN KEY (Type_Transportid) 
REFERENCES Type_Transport (id)); 

CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_Country_destination 
INCREMENT BY 1 
START WITH 1; 

CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_City 
INCREMENT BY 1 
START WITH 1; 

CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_Tour 
INCREMENT BY 1 
START WITH 1; 

CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_Client 
INCREMENT BY 1 
START WITH 1; 

INSERT INTO Country_destination VALUES 
(nextVal('seq_country_destination'),'Russia'); 
INSERT INTO Country_destination VALUES 
(nextVal('seq_country_destination'),'USA'); 
INSERT INTO Country_destination VALUES 
(nextVal('seq_country_destination'),'Egypt');
INSERT INTO City VALUES 
(nextVal('seq_city'),'Moscow'); 
INSERT INTO City VALUES 
(nextVal('seq_city'),'Washington'); 
INSERT INTO City VALUES 
(nextVal('seq_city'),'Kair');
INSERT INTO Tour VALUES 
(nextVal('seq_tour'),10000,'27.11.2017', '23:15'); 
INSERT INTO Tour VALUES 
(nextVal('seq_tour'),15000,'28.12.2017', '14:15'); 
INSERT INTO Tour VALUES 
(nextVal('seq_tour'),20000,'29.07.2017', '22:10');
INSERT INTO Client VALUES 
(nextVal('seq_city'),'Vasili','Ivanov', 612716); 
INSERT INTO Client VALUES 
(nextVal('seq_city'),'Ivan','Fedorov', 123456); 
INSERT INTO Client VALUES 
(nextVal('seq_city'),'Ilya','Sidorov', 654321);


SELECT*FROM Client WHERE number='612716'; 
SELECT*FROM Client ORDER BY Firstname; 
SELECT*FROM Client ORDER BY Firstname DESC;

SELECT number 
FROM Client 
WHERE id IN( 
SELECT Clientid 
FROM Treaty);
```

Как написать вот такие запросы,я новичок в этом,и у меня никак не получается(
1)вывести топ 10 популярных мест(самые частые города ,куда летают)
2)и места на ближайшее лето(вывод кто куда летит на ближайшее лето)
буду благодарен если подскажите

Comment: Это не фриланс биржа, попытайтесь сделать сами как умеете, а сообщество укажет на ошибки.

Comment: Пока я читаю ваш вопрос как "напишите за меня запросы". Обычно мы тут помогаем человеку разобраться с ошибками, подсказываем, но не выполняем всю работу за вас. Соотвественно, постарайтесь написать их сами, если не получится, укажите что не получается и мы подскажем

Comment: Я прошу подсказать,через какие методы и т.д

Comment: Для получения статистики необходима группировка (GROUP BY). Количество считает функция COUNT. Для выбора (наиболее/наименее) используется сортировка (ORDER BY) и отбор заданного количества (LIMIT).